# DropDownList Dynamic Data - ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I am adding to my dropdownlist the first day of the this month and the next two months, The problem is, when I tested this for November, it is going like that:

11/01/2014
12/01/2014
01/01/2014

AS you see, the 01/01/2014 is wrong, it needs to be 01/01/2015, I am not sure how to start this, any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dayone = new DateTime(dt.AddMonths(1).Year, dt.AddMonths(+i).Month, 1);
    DropDownList3.Items.Add(dayone.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is dt.AddMonths(1).Year will always be next month's year.  So, next month is November which is still 2014 and you'll have that in every loop.

This is probably better refactored as:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    DropDownList3.Items.Add(dt.AddMonths(i).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```